# Dimension error with SMOTE for oversampling

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, oversampling

I have a quick question on how to use the SMOTE module in the imblearn library for imbalanced dataset:

I have a dataset to train my DNN model. It has 12442 samples and each sample is a 650*5 array:
X.shape  #  (12442, 650, 5)
y.shape  #  (12442, 1)

The dataset works well with my DNN model built with tf.keras API.

However when I tried to add over sampling with SMOTE, it returns error:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE()
X, y = sm.fit_sample(X, y)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Is it that SMOTE in the imblearn package only takes 1d data? Is there a way or another package to get around it?

Comment: Have you tried reshaping, applying SMOTE and then reshaping again? E.g. `X = X.reshape(12442, -1)`

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak it works! Thanks!